# Django form widgets and the choice is not one of available choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to change the default value of the "true / false" checkboxes to another.

Unfortunately. I receive a form error: “the choice is not one of available choices”.

Please tell me what have I done wrong?

**models.py**

```
CHECKBOX_CHOICES = (('1', 'The first choice'), ('2', 'The Second Choice'))

class Order(models.Model):
        paid = models.CharField(max_length=350, choices=CHECKBOX_CHOICES)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['paid']
 widgets = {
            'paid': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

If I change `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` to `forms.CheckboxInput()`  I receive a form error:

```
Select the correct value. True is not one of the choices available.
```

**create.html**

```
  <form action="." method="post" class="order-form">
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
```

**rendered html**

```
<ul id="id_paid">
    <li><label for="id_paid_0"><input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="" checked="" id="id_paid_0">
 ---------</label>
</li>
    <li><label for="id_paid_1"><input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="1" id="id_paid_1">
 The first choice</label>
</li>
    <li><label for="id_paid_2"><input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="2" id="id_paid_2">
 The Second Choice</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

It's important to me, even though it's a little thing.

Comment: A `CharField` with choices is only meant to store one choice. It doesn't make sense to use a `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, which can be used to select multiple choices.

Comment: it's true. But if i change forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() to forms.CheckboxInput()  I recive a form error: Select the correct value. True is not one of the choices available.

Comment: `CheckboxInput` doesn't really make sense either -- it's meant for a true/false `BooleanField`, not a `CharField` with choices. For a `CharField` with choices, the easiest widgets to use are [`Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#select) or [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

Comment: I agree with you absolutely. But I do not want to use radio or select. I know that the check box have values: true or false. I want the chexbox to have a value other than true or flase ex: yes / no.

Comment: If you don't want to use `Select` or `RadioSelect` then you're going to find yourself fighting against Django. It's probably possible, but it might be tricky and I can't help you with that.

Comment: I appreciate the desire. I have a specification of the form I have to perform. The form design has chexboxs.

Comment: Maybe I should manually render the form and add javascript on the client side. What do you think ?

Comment: As I said, I'm afraid I can't help you if you don't use `Select` or `RadioSelect`.